# How to make multiple cells have the same layout by removing spaces and capitalising

Tags: excel-2010

Loading...

I have a pivot table and loads of names with codes next to them but of course some are repeating because there are probably random extra spaces etc. I wondered if there was a fast way to get around this. Maybe by making every single cell have the same number of spaces. Then I would like everything to become upper case.

for example:

```
dave jim henrys 1233444567

dave  jim  henrys 1233444567
```

should be:

```
DAVE JIM HENRYS 1233444567

DAVE JIM HENRYS 1233444567
```

And in my pivot table should be:

```
DAVE JIM HENRYS 1233444567
```

Can someone please tell me how to so that

Answer (score 0):

To your source data (then refresh PT), please try applying:

```
=UPPER(TRIM(A1))
```